# Нужно сверстать блок 1x4 с выводом фона первого и последнего блока за ширину контейнера

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Ширина контейнера 1170px, каждый блок должен занимать 25%. Как вывести фон первого и последнего блока за ширину контейнера?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.users-box{
    display: flex;
}

.block{
    display: flex;
    width: 25%;
    align-items: center;
    height: 150px;
}

div.users-box .block:nth-child(1){
    background-color: #31D9FF;
}

div.users-box .block:nth-child(2){
    background-color: #68B3FF;
}

div.users-box .block:nth-child(3){
    background-color: #C289FF;
}

div.users-box .block:nth-child(4){
    background-color: #FF81FF;
}
```

```html
      <section class="section-outer">
            <div class="container users-box">
                <div class="block">
                    <img src="img/house.png" alt="pic">
                    <p>12000+ Business</p>
                </div>

                <div class="block">
                    <img src="img/download-blue.png" alt="pic">
                    <p>60000+ Downloads</p>
                </div>

                <div class="block">
                    <img src="img/person.png" alt="pic">
                    <p>30000+ Installs</p>
                </div>

                <div class="block">
                    <img src="img/download-pink.png" alt="pic">
                    <p>40000+ Pro Users</p>
                </div>
            </div> 
        </section>
```

Comment: а что значит "за ширину", т.е. за пределы самого блока?

Comment: Да. Нужно, чтобы фон этих крайних блоков упирался в края монитора, но их контент все также оставался в пределах контейнера 1170px.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPD**

Либо (так, наверное, даже правильнее) использовать псевдоэлементы блока-обёртки: задать им абсолютное позиционирование, разнести по краям и покрасить в цвета крайних блоков

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.section-outer {
  position: relative;
}
.section-outer:before,
.section-outer:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 50%;
}
.section-outer:before {
  left: 0;
  background-color: #31D9FF;
}
.section-outer:after {
  right: 0;
  background-color: #FF81FF;
}
.users-box{
    display: flex;
    max-width: 1170px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.block{
    display: flex;
    width: 25%;
    align-items: center;
    height: 150px;
}

div.users-box .block:nth-child(1){
    background-color: #31D9FF;
}

div.users-box .block:nth-child(2){
    background-color: #68B3FF;
}

div.users-box .block:nth-child(3){
    background-color: #C289FF;
}

div.users-box .block:nth-child(4){
    background-color: #FF81FF;
}
```

```html
<section class="section-outer">
  <div class="container users-box">
    <div class="block">
      <img src="img/house.png" alt="pic">
      <p>12000+ Business</p>
    </div>

    <div class="block">
      <img src="img/download-blue.png" alt="pic">
      <p>60000+ Downloads</p>
    </div>

    <div class="block">
      <img src="img/person.png" alt="pic">
      <p>30000+ Installs</p>
    </div>

    <div class="block">
      <img src="img/download-pink.png" alt="pic">
      <p>40000+ Pro Users</p>
    </div>
  </div> 
</section>
```

Как вариант, использовать псевдоэлементы для крайних блоков, покрашенные в их цвет:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.section-outer {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.users-box{
    display: flex;
    max-width: 1170px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.block{
    display: flex;
    width: 25%;
    align-items: center;
    height: 150px;
}

div.users-box .block:nth-child(1){
    background-color: #31D9FF;
    position: relative;
}
div.users-box .block:nth-child(1):before,
div.users-box .block:nth-child(4):after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 300%;
}
div.users-box .block:nth-child(1):before {
  left: -300%;
  background-color: #31D9FF;
}

div.users-box .block:nth-child(2){
    background-color: #68B3FF;
}

div.users-box .block:nth-child(3){
    background-color: #C289FF;
}

div.users-box .block:nth-child(4){
    background-color: #FF81FF;
    position: relative;
}
div.users-box .block:nth-child(4):after {
  right: -300%;
  background-color: #FF81FF;
}
```

```html
<section class="section-outer">
  <div class="container users-box">
    <div class="block">
      <img src="img/house.png" alt="pic">
      <p>12000+ Business</p>
    </div>

    <div class="block">
      <img src="img/download-blue.png" alt="pic">
      <p>60000+ Downloads</p>
    </div>

    <div class="block">
      <img src="img/person.png" alt="pic">
      <p>30000+ Installs</p>
    </div>

    <div class="block">
      <img src="img/download-pink.png" alt="pic">
      <p>40000+ Pro Users</p>
    </div>
  </div> 
</section>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, шикарное решение!

Comment: @Holvender, рад помочь )